# Entity Framework Problem using two connections with same stored procedure name

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I've got two edmx files in my project that each access a stored procedure with the same name (two different databases).  My problem is that the namespace used for the storage model is the namespace of the project, not the Model Namespace.

This is causing compilation issues as they are seen as the same class.

Any ideas on how to make the classes unique to the model?

I'm using Visual Web Developer Express (.net 4.0) and C# accessing a SQL Server 2005 back-end.

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed:  Just had to set the Custom Tool Namespace on the edmx files.

Answer (score 1):

We put each model in its own folder to avoid this problem. This results in a different namespace for each model.